# Adyen card container accepting unsupported card numbers without error - How to fix?

Tags: adyen

Entered an unsupported card number: 9162 9912 8719 8161 476, in Adyen card container, but didn't get any error saying card number is invalid.
Container takes it in successfully and doesn't validate the digits on input.

Here's the relevant image showing card digits entered and Adyen not returning any error message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBZRj.png)

Answer (score 1):

The card number you are entering is valid and it passes the [luhn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) check. However the card BIN is not in the **Test** databases so the card brand cannot be detected.
In this scenario (on Test only) the card payment is allowed and it is up to the application to decide what to do.

When it comes to the **Live** environment the verification of the card brand and whether you as a merchant, are configured to accept it, take place.
In the scenario that you do not allow this card brand, an "unsupported card" error would be generated in the UI and it would not be possible for the shopper to proceed with the payment.